# Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded - AngularMultiSelect

Tags: angular, npm, multi-select

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at SafeSubscriber.Subscription.unsubscribe (Subscription.js:68)
at SafeSubscriber.Subscriber.unsubscribe (Subscriber.js:123)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:126)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90)
at Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
at DataService.setData (multiselect.service.js:10)
at ListFilterPipe.transform (list-filter.js:11)
at checkAndUpdatePureExpressionInline (core.es5.js:11244)
```

I guess this is releated to AngularMultiSelect.html:4  as it was given in console. 
I am using Angular2-Multiselect-Dropdown module of version 2.1.4 and Angular version 4.0.2 and Angular cli 1.5.4.
Any help will be appreciated.